# Where are Bulk API queries to MetadataComponentDependency supported

Tags: tooling-api, bulk-api

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency_bulk2_usage.htm) suggests that you can query MetadataComponentDependency using the Bulk API.

It seems to work fine in my scratch org sandboxes, but not in a DE org. Does anyone know if this is this a documentation bug, or is it just developer orgs that it doesn't work? Or perhaps it doesn't work in Production orgs either.

In a developer org, I receive the response:

`[ {"errorCode" : "INVALID_TYPE", "message" : "sObject type 'MetadataComponentDependency' is not supported." } ]`

Comment: This works in developer org with tooling api (select MetadataComponentType from MetadataComponentDependency)

Comment: @Vinay yes it works using just Tooling API, but I'm using bulk api, e.g. `/services/data/vXX.X/tooling/jobs/query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_bulk_metadatacomponentdependency_beta.htm&release=226&type=5), Querying MetadataComponentDependency using Bulk API 2.0 is a beta feature and released only in sandboxes, this will be available in production org when it is generally available.

[image]

Comment: I really should pay more attention, thanks for point out the obvious :)